# Task Scheduler 6 days a week

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I have a backup that I run as a scheduled task every night, then clear out every weekday morning after I check it.

Problem is my server's memory is almost maxed out (can't upgrade with my current host, and still researching others), and the weekend backups are leaving me with no memory by Mon morning.

Is there a way to have Windows Task Scheduler run 6 days a week instead of 7?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you select weekly you can select which days your task shall run.